# How to remove username segment from powerline

Tags: macos, bash, iterm2

I'd like to show only the dir name. Right now it's like this:

[image]

I'm using macOS + bash + iTerm. I've tried:

- editing the ~/.config/powerline/config.json
- changing the $PS env (which works without powerline, but not with)

Both without success.

Answer (score 2):

In `~/.config/powerline/themes/shell/default.json` set your username as a value of the `hide_user` argument for the user segment. Like this:

```
          {
            "args": {
              "hide_user": "zebradil"
            },
            "function": "powerline.segments.common.env.user",
            "priority": 30
          },
```

See more in [Powerline docs](https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/master/configuration/segments/common.html#powerline.segments.common.env.user).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
In ~/.config/powerline/themes/shell/default.json
I removed the following code:

```
            {
                "function": "powerline.segments.common.net.hostname",
                "priority": 10
            },
            {
                "function": "powerline.segments.common.env.user",
                "priority": 30
            },
```